# include tar.bz image in wic image

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I want the tar.bz image to be included in the wic image, which is an installer wic image

I have:

```
IMAGE_FSTYPES += "tar.bz2"
do_image_wic[depends] += "${IMAGE_BASENAME}:do_image_tar"
IMAGE_BOOT_FILES += "${IMAGE_BASENAME}-${MACHINE}.tar.bz2;upgrade.bz2"
```

so the tar.bz is made first, but... it is not deployed at the point the wic images is made, it is in:

```
build_output/work/device-type-linux/yocto-image-release/1.0-r0/deploy-yocto-image-release-image-complete/yocto-image-release-device-type-20190611214913.rootfs.tar.bz2
```

It won't appear in the deploy dir until after image yocto-image-release:do_deploy which naturally occurs after the wic is built (which now fails).

Is there a safe way to access that for the wic imager?
I'm guessing work-shared won't be any good https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#structure-build-work-shared

Is the better way to have a new installer.bb which depends on the yocto-image-release.bb:do_deploy so it can find the pieces and then make its own wic?

Answer (score 0):

One solution seems to involve `BBCLASSEXTEND` so that I can build `bitbake yocto-image-release` and `bitbake yocto-image-installer` by amending the recipe (or a parent class) to include:

```
BBCLASSEXTEND += "installer"
DEPENDS_installer += "${BPN}"
```

and in `installer.bbclass`:

```
CLASSOVERRIDE = "installer"
```

and then I can override values with _installer suffix, although there will likely be a lot of work neutralising most of the configuration and methods of the native recipe, because (for now) all I want to build is a wic with the systems own kernel.

No doubt later it will have its own kernel configuration and initramfs anyway as the installer specialises.

This seems nice as there are a variety of images (-dev, -debug, etc) all of which may want an installer. But I still wonder if `-installer` couples the two too tightly